# Approval workflow: Is it possible to make workflow approver depend on the starter of the workflow?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, infopath

I'm trying to create an approval workflow in order to get rid of a cumbersome paper based document process. Basic idea is that user fills a form and then submits it. The submit should start the workflow and send the form for the appropriate approvers. This usually means user's manager and HR personnel.

My question is: How can I limit the approvers so that the user from Team1 doesn't send the document for all the managers in the office but only to Team1's manager and HR personnel?

So basically it would depend on the user's team for which manager the approval workflow should be directed to.

Comment: do you have it stored somewhere that the logged in  user's manager is a person XYZ?. Normally these kind of information should be available in User profile . It has a manager column.

Comment: @Unnie Well, the user profiles come from AD and there we have a manager set on the Organization tab. But I don't know how to utilize that if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint designer workflow then the workflow initiator variable is supported OOTB in SharePoint Designer.

basically if you want to set the initiator as a approver you need to do the following stuffs:

1. Create a workflow that starts every time an item is created.
2. Create variable set the value with ,the data source would be "Workflow Context" and the field is, of course, "Initiator" and you can choose to return it as the "Display Name", "Email", "Login Name" or the "User ID Number".
3. Set the Approver column of list with the above variable.
4. your further steps...